# How do you refresh the MySQL configuration file without restarting?

Tags: mysql, database

Apache has such a feature, what about MySQL?

Does one exist?

Comment: Server Fault has a better answer to the same question: http://serverfault.com/a/79051

Answer (score 28):

You were so close! The `kill -HUP` method wasn't working for me either.

You were calling:

```
select @@global.max_connections;
```

All you needed was to set instead of select:

```
set @@global.max_connections = 400;
```

See:

http://www.netadmintools.com/art573.html

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/update-max-connections-mysql/

Comment: what is the context of this answer?

Answer (score 23):

Try:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql reload
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql force-reload
```

That should initiate a reload of the configuration.  Make sure your init.d script supports it though, I don't know what version of MySQL/OS you are using?

My MySQL script contains the following:

```
'reload'|'force-reload')
        log_daemon_msg "Reloading MySQL database server" "mysqld"
        $MYADMIN reload
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
```

Comment: Seems not working,I'm using mysql5.1,I added in [mysqld] section:transaction-isolation = READ-UNCOMMITTED,and after running your script,
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;
+-----------------------+-----------------+
| @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation | @@tx_isolation  |
+-----------------------+-----------------+
| REPEATABLE-READ       | REPEATABLE-READ | 
+-----------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>

Comment: mysql reload should reload all the grant tables and configuration.  What was the outcome of running it?

Comment: none of above works,I've restarted mysql and then it works,thank you anyway!

Comment: I'm changing the configurations of 3 slave databases,after modifying my.cnf,I used your script,but seems not working,only after I restarted 1 of them,I see the output:

mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;
+-----------------------+------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation | @@tx_isolation   |
+-----------------------+------------------+
| READ-UNCOMMITTED      | READ-UNCOMMITTED | 
+-----------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

say,it changed to READ-UNCOMMITTED,which is what I did in my.cnf

Comment: I preferred to comment instead of downvoting this answer, as the OP asks a way of reloading configuration and not privileges.

Comment: Yes, It does not for reloading configuration. I'm on Debian wheezy and reload or force-reload does nothing for me after changing my connection limit. It only actually changes after restart.

Comment: Running `/etc/init.d/mysql reload` restarted my server instead of reloading (MySQL 5.8 running on Docker)

Comment: Note that a `reload` translates to `stop` followed by `start` on Debian and Ubuntu. This might make your users unhappy if they have an active session.
The only way around this in Mysql is to `set global <var> = <value>`. Kinda painful, really.

Answer (score 12):

Reloading the configuration file (`my.cnf`) cannot be done without restarting the `mysqld` server.

`FLUSH LOGS` only rotates a few log files.

`SET @@...=...` sets it *for anyone not yet logged in*, but it will go away after the next restart.  But that gives a clue...  Do the `SET`, *and* change `my.cnf`; that way you are covered.  Caveat:  Not all settings can be performed via `SET`.

**New with MySQL 8.0**...

`SET PERSIST ...` will set the global setting *and* save it past restarts.  Nearly all settings can be adjusted this way.

Answer (score 2):

Specific actions you can do from SQL client and you don't need to restart anything:

```
SET GLOBAL log = 'ON';
FLUSH LOGS;
```