# Fastest way to reload mysql databases in perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a script that needs to add data to a folder created in the mysql data folder and then in some way force the mysql server to reload the data so the database reliably shows up. I am currently using a `system` call to the `/etc/init.d/mysql` script to restart the server but this is quite slow, I couldn't find anyhting in mysql that would reload the database through a query of some kind.. I was just wondering if there was a way to do this that was slightly quicker?

Comment: Maybe a config reload will work, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917865/how-do-you-refresh-the-mysql-configuration-file-without-restarting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the storage engine you're using.

MyISAM tables will be reloaded automatically as soon as the table is next touched by MySQL (obviously, you need to make sure the .MYI, .MYD and .frm files are consistent).

InnoDB is a bit more complex, and depends on whether it's a traditional configuration with all tables in the same tablespace, or if you're using `innodb_file_per_table`. With the former, you pretty much have to restart the server. With file-per-table, you can copy individual .ibd files, but then you have to use an `ALTER TABLE` statement to import that tablespace.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html) for information on working with individual .ibd files without restarting the server.

[This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-migration.html) is also useful for seeing how to move InnoDB data from place to place.

Comment: Agreed, this OP doesn't want to restart the entire system to do this and perl has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'quite slow'?

You could do a dump/load of the *new* db in a one named `orginal_db_name_temp`, rename the `original` DB, and then rename `orginal_db_name_temp` to `orginal_db_name` - then you will have your new DB in place.

However, I don't know which method is faster by your means - because a dump&load roundtrip will be probably slower than a file-copy. But renaming the DBs will probably be faster than restarting the server